# How do increase the selected area number dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $fullname = $row['full_name'];
    $roll = $row['roll'];
    $s_result = $row['result'];
    $gm = $row['gm'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th scope='row'>1</th>";
    echo "<td>{$fullname}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$roll}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$s_result}</td>";
    echo "<td>$gm</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

[image: The Image]

I want to increase the selected number. Right now its hardcoded. How do I increase the number dynamically? If I enter more data then I want the number will increase automatically.

Comment: Have you not an AUTO_INCREMENT'ed column? That would be easier and echo out the id's dynamically with a variable for it. Your question is a bit unclear though and what the query looks like.

Comment: I sorted the list. So the id will be random.

Comment: If it's to be random, you can always do an ORDER BY.

Comment: From his comment i suspect the order is on purpose and thus the id will be random. Moumita why not just use a counter($i = 1 and then $i++)?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM computer ORDER BY result DESC";
I do an order by

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a little addition:

```
$counter = 1; // set a counter
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $fullname = $row['full_name'];
    $roll = $row['roll'];
    $s_result = $row['result'];
    $gm = $row['gm'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th scope='row'>$counter</th>"; // use the counter
    echo "<td>{$fullname}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$roll}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$s_result}</td>";
    echo "<td>$gm</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $counter++; // increase the counter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take an global variable above `while` loop and initialize it to `1` then print as it is and increase on every iteration, it would be printed in  serial number.

```
$index = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $fullname = $row['full_name'];
    $roll = $row['roll'];
    $s_result = $row['result'];
    $gm = $row['gm'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th scope='row'>$index</th>";
    echo "<td>{$fullname}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$roll}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$s_result}</td>";
    echo "<td>$gm</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $index = $index + 1;
}
```